# Webpack - copy certain files and keep their respectively original path

Tags: webpack

I basically have this workspace:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/90b1f2f3c55f209099c8a87550e357fe.png]

I have this actual webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: 'src/**',
          test: /\.lua?$/,
          to: 'resources',
          transformPath (targetPath, absolutePath) {
              console.log(targetPath)
              console.log(absolutePath)
            return targetPath;
          }
        }
      ], { debug: 'info' })
  ],
  entry: {
    "resources/[Test]/izitest/izitest_server": "./src/[Test]/izitest/main.ts"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  }
};
```

I want to copy all .lua files from the `./src` directory to `./resources` and keep their original places.
Like, file `A.lua`: `src/moduleA/A.lua` goes to `resources/moduleA/A.lua`.

I tried to implement a `transformPath` but didn't succeed it!

Also, looks like `test` isn't returning all the `.lua` files since he catch the `.ts` too

Any original ways to do this?